# Modifying images for better OCR

Tags: imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract for optical character recognization of images which contain only single character per image but I'm having some problem in recognizing some characters.

I'm cropping the characters from a larger image and am saving them with `pbm` extension using `convert`. Here are some sample images :

[image: Letter S][image: Letter T][image: Letter P][image: Letter E]

These are four separate images. Letters 'S', 'P' and 'E' are recognized correctly but the letter 'T' is is not being recognized. There's a problem with few other characters too. Here's how I'm using the tesseract :

```
tesseract character.pbm stdout -l eng -psm 10
```

So, is there any way that I can improve the results? May be modifying the image in some way with `convert`?

Comment: Works fine for me as follows `convert t.png  -threshold 50% pgm: | tesseract stdin stdout -l eng -psm 10`

Comment: Remember that you can always remove artefacts with apropriate morphology. For example `convert badT.png -morphology Open Disk:1 goodT.png`.